# How to remove BOM (byte order mark) from rsyslog messages

Tags: python, unicode, syslog, byte-order-mark, rsyslog

In my current rsyslog messages, there are a lot BOMs showing up like `<feff`> in the log messages. Is there any way I can get rid of these BOMs in the log messages? I'm using rsyslog 8.10. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might actually be caused by a bug in older versions of Python. Do you know if your Python version on the system is up to date? If not, you might try updating it to whatever the latest Python 2.7 is that you can get for the system.

Related bug reports:

- *Prepending BOM to UTF8 message before sending to rsyslog causes bad characters in log* http://bugzilla.adiscon.com/show_bug.cgi?id=346
- *UTF8 BOM incorrectly prepended syslog messages when using rsysolog* http://bugs.python.org/issue15462
- *SysLogHandler sends invalid messages when using unicode*
  http://bugs.python.org/issue14452

Short of updating to a new Python 2.7 version, tt seems the only way to work around this is for an older Python 2.7 install is to apply the following patch to the `/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py` file on your system.

```
@@ -797,9 +797,10 @@
                                             self.mapPriority(record.levelname))
         # Message is a string. Convert to bytes as required by RFC 5424
         if type(msg) is unicode:
            msg = msg.encode('utf-8')
- if codecs:
- msg = codecs.BOM_UTF8 + msg
+ #if codecs:
+ # msg = codecs.BOM_UTF8 + msg
         msg = prio + msg
         try:
             if self.unixsocket:
```

For a Python 2.6 system, I think you might instead need the following patch to the `/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/handlers.py` file on the system.

```
@@ -821,8 +821,6 @@ class SysLogHandler(logging.Handler):
         # Message is a string. Convert to bytes as required by RFC 5424
         if type(msg) is unicode:
             msg = msg.encode('utf-8')
-            if codecs:
-                msg = codecs.BOM_UTF8 + msg
         msg = prio + msg
         try:
             if self.unixsocket:
```

Comment: Python version we are using right now is 2.6, and I can't personally update the Python version right now as that's the version determined by the management. Does that mean there is no solution for this issue yet? By the way, do you have any reference I may use to show the management that this is an issue caused by older version of Python that I can't fix at this time? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I updated my answer to add links to some related rsyslog and Python bug reports. As far as a solution, the right solution is to update the Python environment to a newer Python 2.7 version that has this fix. But if you can’t do that, I think the only workaround is to patch the `/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/handlers.py` file on the system, with the change indicated in the second patch in my answer (essentially, removing the code that does `msg = codecs.BOM_UTF8 + msg`).

Comment: What is the relationship here with Python?  There's no mention of Python at all in the question.

Comment: The relationship with Python is that the root cause of the problem is a Python bug, in older the Python logging code. One place where that Python logging-code bug causes problems is in ryslog messages. So I think adding the `python` tag to the question might help others to find this answer later. But that said, I agree that adding the `python` tag to the question might be overkill in this case, since the question itself doesn’t mention Python. (Maybe we need a way to tag answers…)